# In Python selenium, how to get return texts from class having same name?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to capture product size of a web page using selenium python

```
<h4 class="product-sizes">
 <!-- react-text: 510 -->Sizes: 
 <!-- /react-text -->
 <span class="product-sizeInventoryPresent">UK6,
 </span><span class="product-sizeInventoryPresent">UK7,
 </span><span class="product-sizeInventoryPresent">UK8,
 </span><span class="product-sizeInventoryPresent">UK9,
 </span><span class="product-sizeInventoryPresent">UK10,
 </span><span class="product-sizeInventoryPresent">UK11
</span>
</h4>
```

Basically, the output should have all sizes listed under class `product-sizeInventoryPresent` i.e. size = [UK6, UK7, UK8, UK9, UK10, UK11].
So far I tried this,

```
sizes = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('product-sizes')
size_list = []
for size in sizes:
    size_list.append(size.text)
```

but it returns an empty list. Mainly because `product-sizeInventoryPresent` is visible only if I hover over the element.

Comment: Try `items = [''.join(i.text.split()) for i in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//h4[contains(.,'Sizes:')]/span[contains(@class,'sizeInventoryPresent')]")]`

Comment: It still returns empty string. I guess because the sizes are not visible until I hover the mouse over that layout.

Comment: How would anyone  help you without knowing what is happening out there?

Comment: Sorry mate, I just found out myself after posting. I updated the question now, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In selenium, after you find a parent element, you can use the parent to search the child elements.

Try this code:

```
parent = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('product-sizes')[0] # first in list
sizes = parent.find_elements_by_class_name('product-sizeInventoryPresent')  # children
size_list = []
for size in sizes:
    size_list.append(size.text)
    
print(size_list)
```

Output

```
['UK6,', 'UK7,', 'UK8,', 'UK9,', 'UK10,', 'UK11']
```

Comment: It's still return empty. I guess because the sizes are not visible until I hover the mouse over that layout.But what I observed is the solution you proposed only returns for one class, not for all similar class names.